# Valuing stock employee compensation securities

Tags: options, option-pricing

This may be a simple question but I wonder if Im oversimplifying it. I'm trying to decide how to value different Stock Employee compensations and in particular a Stock Appreciation Rights (SAR) Reward. A good definition is provided [here](https://www.morganstanley.com/spc/knowledge/managing-equity/understanding-your-awards/glossary-of-stock-plan-awards.html). Assuming I am modeling the Stock Option prices via a standard Black Scholes framework, with continuous constant dividends, can I just use the same framework to model the SAR, except taking the Strike Price as 0? I assume no turnover or intervening event.

Thanks

**Edit**: Strike Price should be the stock price at the time of granting and not 0.

Comment: The Strike Price of a SAR is not zero, but whatever the stock price was when the SAR was granted.

Comment: @AlexC Sorry, yes. I will make that edit. Would using the standard Black Scholes Option price formulation with this different Strike Price make sense or are there other changes that I am not taking into account as compared to a Stock Option? Thanks

Comment: From a quant point of view this SAR is just like a call option.